# how to enforce the user to enter case comment on each status change

Tags: trigger, validation-rule

I got a requirement to enforce the user to enter case comment on each status change. So are there any ways to validate that a case comment is entered when a status change is made on case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

1. create a checkbox field on Case named 'New Case Comment'
2. create a workflow rule + field update on Case Comment that ticks the checkbox on the parent Case upon creation of a new Case Comment
3. create a validation rule on Case that checks if the status is changed and the checkbox is not ticked. In that case raise an error
4. create a workflow rule on Case that unticks the checkbox whenever the status is changed and the previous value of the checkbox was 'ticked'